# React Router DOM History Object Causes Typescript Error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

I'm having an issue wherein I have a stateless component that gets passed the History object from `react-router-dom` and passes that object down to a stateful object through props. Typescript doesn't seem to think I can pass the history object down as a prop.

Here are my components

```
import { History } from 'history';
import * as React from 'react';
import { RouteComponentProps, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

const SignInPage = ({ history }: { history: History }) =>
  <div>
    <h1>SignIn</h1>
    <SignInForm history={history} />
  </div>

class SignInForm extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps<{}>, {}> {

  constructor(props: RouteComponentProps<{}>) {
    super(props);
  }

  public handleClick = () => {
    const { history } = this.props;
    history.push('/home')
  };

  public render() {

    return (
      <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Sign In!</button>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(SignInPage);

export { SignInForm };
```

And the error I get is this.

```
Type '{ history: History; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<SignInForm> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }> ...'.
  Type '{ history: History; }' is not assignable to type 'Readonly<RouteComponentProps<{}, StaticContext>>'.
    Property 'location' is missing in type '{ history: History; }'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never used React Router, but if I understand the typings properly, by declaring `SignInForm extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps<{}>, {}>`, you are saying that `SignInForm` requires *all* the props that a route component normally receives when called by React Router.  Since you are calling it yourself and passing it only the history, you should just declare it as `SignInForm extends React.Component<{history: History}, {}>`.

Comment: You are correct Matt, that does fix the error. I am curious, however, how you would handle a situation where the `SignInForm` component uses multiple props from `ReactComponentProps` (i.e. the `location` prop) but the `SignInPage` component only needs to pass down the `history` prop to `SignInForm`? Something makes me feel like I want to keep the `ReactComponentProps` there so I have access to all the props in `SignInForm` even though my `SignInPage` component doesn't need to pass every prop down.

Comment: But at runtime, you only have access to the props that `SignInPage` actually passes down.  If you want access to several of them, it may be easiest to pass them all:
    const SignInPage = (props: RouteComponentProps<{}>) =>
      <div>
        <h1>SignIn</h1>
        <SignInForm {...props} />
      </div>